# Access JavaScript Variable in SVG? Current Time in SVG

Tags: javascript, interface, svg

I've been Googling and trying to find out how to do this, but I'm coming up with nothing.
How do I access a JavaScript variable in SVG?

I'm working on an interface written in SVG, but I need to get the current date and time, format them, and display it.

I'm trying

```
<text id="epgDate" x="1130" class="epg-date text" text-anchor="end" width="180">

    <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
    setInterval( currentDate, 1000);
    ]]></script>

</text>
<text id="epgTime" x="1170" class="epg-time text">

    <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
    setInterval( currentTime, 1000);
    ]]></script>

</text>
```

with "currentDate()" and "currentTime()" defined elsewhere.

This is giving me some form of syntax error (I'm using a client's emulator tool to run this interface, so it doesn't tell me anything more specific).
**EDIT**
Syntax error was somewhere else, and it's fixed.
However, this still does not work. Even when I try to use a trivial function such as "alert('x')" or "document.write('x')".

Does anyone either know how to get the current DateTime in SVG, or t get it in JavaScript and echo it out periodically using setInterval()?

Much thanks for any help ahead of time!

Comment: Please provide a simple, standalone test file that fully reproduces your problem. SVG in a web browser has full access to JavaScript objects and methods, sharing the same global 'window' object with the page. Try using http://jsfiddle.net/ if you can't host a test file yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the confusion I was having was the difference between SVG and HTML markup pages. SVG uses a slightly different DOM, so accessing / setting elements does not always work in exactly the same way or use the same methods.

I wrote this script and I was able to set the datetime for SVG drawn date and time  elements:

```
<script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[

                // Format Date
                var date = new Date();
                var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                var day = date.getDate();
                var year = date.getFullYear();

                var monthsByName = ["January", "February", "March",     "April", "May", "June", "July",
                    "August","September", "October", "November", "December"];

                var formattedDate = monthsByName[month - 1] + " " + day + ", " + year;

                var textNode = document.createTextNode(formattedDate);
                document.getElementById("epg-date").appendChild(textNode);

                // Format Time
                    // Source: bbrame @ StackOverflow
                var hours = date.getHours();
                var minutes = date.getMinutes();
                var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
                hours = hours % 12;
                hours = hours ? hours : 12;
                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0"+minutes : minutes;

                var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;

                var timeNode = document.createTextNode(formattedTime);
                document.getElementById("epg-time").appendChild(timeNode);

            ]]></script>
```